# Non-terminating program when trying to read and write from Microsoft Access database with C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, .net-core

I am trying to read from a Microsoft Access database with C# with the below code.

```
static void getProducts()
{
    string accessDBPath = @"C:\Users\...\dummydb.accdb";
    string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=" + accessDBPath;
    string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Products";
    try
    {
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
           connection.Open();
           OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, connection);
           OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
           while (reader.Read())
           {
               Console.WriteLine("product name = ...");
           }
        }
     }
     catch (OleDbException ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
     } 
     finally
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Finished");
     }
}
```

I'm able to walk through the products table just fine (i.e., the stuff inside the `while(reader.Read()){...}` prints as expected), and the `finally` block prints as expected as well.

But after the function is done running, the program just never terminates, and the command line just freezes. When I try to force the program to quit at the end of my `Main` function with `Environment.Exit(0);`, I get hit with this error:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

The `using` clause should have automatically closed the database connection when I'm finished with it, but it seemingly behaves as if I hadn't, so I have no clue what's going on, and would appreciate any help.

EDIT: Copy-paste error, declared a variable twice.

Comment: Did you check if the program flow returns to whatever call _GetProducts_?

Comment: @Steve yes it does. If I call the function in my Main block, and then print something at the end of Main, the thing gets printed, but the program still doesn't terminate.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is in main then. Could you add the code that call GetProducts?

Comment: @Steve simply running `getProducts(); Console.WriteLine("hello");` from Main results in a non-terminating program :(

Comment: Wait, you have two calls to _new OleDbConnection_ the first one is just before the line with the using statement.

Comment: @Steve my bad, copy-paste error. The program freezes with one call.

Comment: `OleDbCommand` is also disposable, not just the connection. Declare the DbCommand with a `using` statement and open the connection after you have declared it (still passing the Connection object as you're doing now). -- Call the `Close()` method of the DataReader after the loop. Or, if you declare the DataReader beforehand, in the `finally` block.

Comment: @Jimi this still doesn't work... I'm using [this OleDb](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.OleDb/) package v.6.0.0 installed via the .NET CLI and I'm getting the exact same problem on both Windows 10 and Windows 11 machines. I tried enclosing the `OleDbCommand` in a `using` statement and closing the `reader`, but the same problem still occurs. I even commented out everything related to the command and the reader (leaving only the `OleDbConnection` and `connection.Open()` inside the `using` block), yet my program still freezes.

Comment: My comment is related to the code you posted and to that code alone. I have no idea what kind of setup you have there, since you didn't mentioned it. You tagged the question `.net-core`, which means nothing. I don't know what .Net version you're actually targeting, how the application (Console? What System Target?) is configured,  how you installed `System.Data.OleDb` or whether it's installed correctly (note that this makes the app Windows-only) -- If you're targeting .Net Core 3.1 or earlier, just don't.

Comment: Remove the package, remove the `System.Data.OleDb` directive, put the caret over the now squiggling OleDbConnection, press `ALt+ENTER` and, from the menu, select `Install Package System.Data.OleDb -> Find and Install latest version`.  Make sure your app CPU target is set to `AnyCPU`, since `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16` is either x86 or x64 and you need to use the version that matches the bitness of your app. Try again, with the previously suggested modifications. -- Post the app's .Net version and configuration details. Also the version of the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16` installed.

Comment: @Jimi I ended up fixing the problem using a different method of reading the database, thanks for your help!